# Retrieveing Maximum capacity units for a Provisioned table in DynamoDB via AWS SDK

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

Is it possible to query the maximum via DynamoDB AWS SDK, preferably  with the AWS SDK for Java 2.x ?

To be more specific, the value you input in the Maximum capacity units when you create or edit a DDB table with capacity mode set to provisioned.

[image: DDB table capacity]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When in on-demand capacity mode, DynamoDB does not use autoscaling so there is no min and max as you'd imagine when comparing it to provisioned. While there is a maximum, you can always scale to double your previous peak instantly. In its current form, the previous peak does not come down.

If you are using on-demand mode and require a throughput of more than 4k WCU or 12k RCU then you can consider [pre-warming](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.ReadWriteCapacityMode.html#HowItWorks.PreWarming) your on-demand table where you set the previous peak manually.

Currently you are unable to use the SDK to understand the maximum directly via a single lookup call.

---

Update based on change of ask:

For provisioned capacity you need to use `DescribeScalableTarget` as the autoscaling is handled by Application Autoscaling:

https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/applicationautoscaling/ApplicationAutoScalingClient.html#describeScalableTargets(software.amazon.awssdk.services.applicationautoscaling.model.DescribeScalableTargetsRequest)

Comment: I made a mistake in the title of the question I was wondering if it is possible to find the max for a provisioned table. The description and the image are still correct.

Comment: Updated based on your ask.

Comment: The link points to deregisterScalableTarget instead of describe